# Copying data in into same table and changing one row

Tags: sql, copy

I have one table from which I need to copy data into the same table but I have to change one row during this. The table is full of clients and I basicaly need to duplicate them, but also change one row (eg organization 1 -> 2).

I am really struggling with this and I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Which `technology? html/Ado.Net/Sql Server/php/Jquery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you `did not provide` actual sql to modify .. just providing a `pattern` which you may use to do your work

```
INSERT INTO SameTable (
    Id
    ,NAME
    ,Url
    ,ParentId
    ,[Status]
    )
SELECT Id
    ,NAME
    ,Url
    ,ParentId
    ,CASE [Status]
        WHEN '0'
            THEN 'SomeThing1'
        WHEN '1'
            THEN 'SomeThing2'
        ELSE 'SomeThing3' 
FROM SameTable AS s1 
WHERE organization > 2
```